# Bernstein's minimal surface problem

Tags: reference-request

Does anyone know some good reference for this? For your convenience, here's the Wikipedia page on it, on which you can find the statement and the problem proposed: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_problem

Specifically, I'm looking for:

- A good solution on the case n=3, i.e the case that Bernstein proved that a graph of a real function on $R^2$ that is also a minimal surface in $R^3$ must be a plane.
- Some additional information, e.g usage of the theorem, history etc.
- (If possible) a proof why the statement is true in dimensions at most 8 but false in dimensions at least 9.

I've looked around online a decent amount of time and found a few papers, including ones by WY Hsiang and P Tomter, but was wondering if there were more than that written on the topic.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The first bullet item is covered in: Nitsche, Johannes C. C.
*Elementary proof of Bernstein's theorem on minimal surfaces*,
Ann. of Math. (2) 66 (1957), 543–544. [JSTOR link](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1969907?origin=crossref). (NB: a 2-page paper in the Annals of Math.) // If you have access to MathSciNet, [this review](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=250205) of the Bombieri-De Giorgi-Giusti paper covers the main historical points.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you!