# Who is $r$, $t$ and $s$ in this complex variable context?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry

I was trying to understand Nitsche's *Elementary Proof of Bernstein's Theorem on Minimal Surfaces* (referenced on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272566/bernsteins-minimal-surface-problem)) but on the very first page, the statement reads:

*Let the function $z = z(x,y)$ be twice continuously differentiable and satisfy the equation $rt-s^2 = 1$, $r > 0$ for  all values of $x$ and $y$. Then $z(x,y)$ is a quadratic polynomial.*

I have not understood who $r$, $t$ and $s$ are. At first I thought that $z = r + is$ and $t$ is some real number but then the functions $p,q$ appear and it would make so much more sense that $z = p + iq$. Any help or insight is appreciated.

Comment: $x, y, z$ are real values. The graph of $(x, y, z(x,y))$ is a surface. I'm pretty sure that $r, s, t$ are various functions definable from the surface, for instance curvature and torsion at each point. However, I do not recognize the symbolism, so I cannot tell you which functions they are.

Answer (score 1):

Upon looking in further into reference *[2]* in the article I found that
\begin{align}
r = z_{xx}\\
s = z_{xy}\\
t = z_{yy}
\end{align}
And so, for $z$ to be a solution to equation posted in the question it means that 
$$
z_{xx}z_{yy} - z_{xy}^2 = 1
$$